# What is the etymology behind したっけ

Tags: etymology, dialects

僕だけがいない街 anime shows the children saying したっけ! translated as 'See ya!' and other terms, these are from Hokkaido dialect.

I guess you can switch したっけ to other forms to say 'See ya': じゃあまた また明日

Anyway, there's any relation with 明日? What is the etymology resulted in したっけ?

The way that したっけ sounds, it's like an affirmation than a question.

Comment: っけ is actually a "recollective" particle, used in self-address. Do you have more context? This might be of interest: http://maggiesensei.com/2013/09/08/casual-suffix-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%91kke-%E3%80%80/

Comment: @user11589 not related to what OP is asking about

Comment: I think したっけ's main meaning is したかもしれない or したかなあ.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki then why this word converged to "See you soon" meaning?

Comment: I don't know したっけ is see you soon.If you read japanese http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1247294312

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, this phrase isn't cognate with Standard Japanese あした.

したっけ literally means what in Standard Japanese そうしたら. The demonstrative そう is omitted because the whole context before is considered to stand in place of it (colloquial omission of this そう is also common in Tokyo). The っけ part shares the same origin with Standard [っけ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/65853/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%91/) ("(what) again?"), that is Classical indirect past [けり](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/68898/meaning/m0u/), but has diverged from it to mean "(after it) then".

Thus, Hokkaido-ites say "Now then!" to mean "See you!", but this is exactly parallel to Standard Japanese too, where さようなら literally means さよう ("so") + なら ("if be — then") in older way of speaking.

**EDIT**
したっけ is seemingly used in [the same meaning in Ibaraki dialect, too](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%91). Hokkaido dialect is a mish-mash of various Honshu dialects, so it's possible that this part of grammar was exported from Northern Kanto.

Comment: Considering a *mish-mash*, do you know if Hokkaido dialect also include any Ainu roots?

Comment: @sumitani Um, I've heard that they have a small Ainu vocabulary (and the most of their place names are Ainu), but grammar itself is Japanese.

Comment: さらば is another expression for taking leave which is conditional in form, also containing さ meaning something like そう.

Comment: @jogloran This pattern seems to be the standard in Japanese farewell greetings, from さらば to じゃあね.

Comment: @broccoli forest Is there a name to give about these kind of patterns?

Comment: @sumitani Maybe not for specific words. For systems that share many common ideas you could say "[parallel evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_evolution)" or "[sprachbund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachbund)".

Comment: ありがとうございます！
したっけ was bothering me so much, because I had never heard it and could not find the proper translation. I almost thought it was a childish slang way of saying, "see you."
Very glad to see a well written explanation. したっけ、ばいばーい(笑)

Answer (score 1):

したっけ is a Hokkaido-dialect word, which means "See you".

Maybe most natives do not know it.

Comment: The OP asks about the etymology, not the meaning.

Comment: Oops. I would like to delete this since broccoli forest's answer is far better.

The only thing I would like to add is that "さようなら" is an abbreviation of "さようならば、ごきげんよう", "Then, be in a good humor."