# What does he say to his teacher?

Tags: translation, words

I watched the animated version of Erased on Netflix and now there is a live action version. I noticed in both a phrase being used but I can’t work out what it is.

https://www.netflix.com/title/80173711

If you go to 20:30 in episode 2.

Satoru is talking to his teacher. Before he leaves he says “ありがとう先生...” and then something that sounds like “shitake” or something.

They also say it among friends as a sort of goodbye or see you later.

But I can’t find what they’re actually saying.

Adding some subtitles...

[image]

I’m still not sure what he’s saying looking at the subtitles. But could someone please help me (I’m still learning and not very good with kanji). And that katakana has me even more confused.

Comment: I live in Japan, so I'm used to having Japanese subtitles available on the Japanese Netflix, but are there none available for you?

Comment: @Leebo of course! Why didn’t I think of that! I was watching with English subtitles to learn but yeah, Japanese subtitles are there. Watching again now. :-)

Comment: @Leebo added a picture of he subtitles because I’m still not sure. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about フフッ? That's the teacher's laugh... The other thing I thought you were asking about is したっけ, which is I see in the subtitles fairly clearly, and if you check Jisho it's Hokkaido dialect for "goodbye".

Comment: @Leebo yes, I was asking about the goodbye. That explains it! Thanks! (Add it as an answer and I’ll accept)

Comment: @Leebo oh man. I’m so stupid. I stopped before it got to the subtitles I was talking about. Haha. I just continued it and saw the したっけ thanks for explanation of it though.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32697/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

したっけ is Hokkaido dialect for goodbye.

https://jisho.org/search/shitakke